# outlook connection status multiple display names

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server

I notice when I check my outlook connection status that the display names for my SMTP-connection are different. eg.

SMTP Address - Display Name
myid@domain.com - anotherid@domain.com

I've looked at multiple google searches and I cannot seem to find an explanation

I am trying to figure out why would there be different values between - SMTP address and display name.

When I right click on the outlook tab and go to connection status I am able to see multiple connections including this one but still have no idea as to why there are different values in the Display Name column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible reason why there are multiple display names see in the Outlook Connection Status:
[image]

are:

- You have multiple different accounts configured
- You have shared mailboxes configured
- You have different session types (e.g. Foreground, Cache, ...)

So for example for a single user you could see 3 sessions listed as follows:

- 2x connections with a Type of Mail (one session type of Background and the other Cache)
- 1x connection with type of Directory (session type foreground)

This is due to the following:

*Sess Type: Cache / Foreground (Type: Exchange Mail)*

Is used to perform synchronization operations (item synchronization) when using Exchange Cached mode. Another Mail type is reserved for sending new messages.

*Sess Type: Background (Type: Exchange Directory)*

Is used for sync GAL or OAB information.

P.S.
Multiple different sessions are mostly expected and you do not really to be worried about that. See [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/onthewire/2014/07/08/how-to-analyse-application-level-performance-for-outlook-and-sharepoint-online/) if you wish to troubleshoot the performance with that.